# Win8 App Authentication problems when using Fiddler with HTTPS decryption

Tags: c#, authentication, fiddler

I installed fiddler2 to view how goes the api connection with my application.But since I installed it, I have security problems that occurs.For example, I want to open gmail, There is a message that say "Attention it isn't secured do you want to continue?"

In my application, I had a connection required but I have a message "You can't authanticate please check your internet connection" there was also an other message but I don't remember.

I have the internet connection.In my application I have to query Twitter API. But without authantication I can't do that.

When I try to search a user, I have "No message from Twitter" exception.What can I do?

I think it is a problem with fiddler2 but I don't find it!

Someone can help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: First things first. Restart your computer. If you think its Fiddler(doubt it) uninstall it. Fiddler is just a proxy that turns on when the app is opened.

Comment: Does that appear when you *run* fiddler or just installing it? While running fiddler, it will intercept SSL connections which basically is a man-in-the-middle attack. Although you *want* fiddler to do this to make it work, it's more than appropriate to also warn you that your security is compromised.

Comment: @JeremyChild I will restart it ok; I have to see what happens when my application is querying Twitter.

Comment: @nvoigt yes it appears when Fiddler is running... I can't uninstall this because I need to view what happens when my program is querying Twitter. I can't view that in my logFile...

Comment: Let's step back to the very beginning. When Fiddler asked you whether you'd like to TRUST its root certificate, did you say "Yes"? If not, disable HTTPS decryption and re-enable it. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/14/fiddler-and-windows-8-metro-style-applications-https-and-private-network-capabilities.aspx for more information.

Comment: Also, did you remember to run EnableLoopback.exe to allow access to Fiddler from BOTH your application and the Win8 AuthHost appcontainer?

Comment: @Kevser61: I have a similar problem, did you fix yours? I am not using Fiddler and since today half of my queries return "No message from Twitter".

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled HTTPS intercept in fiddler options, it is most likely Fiddler is causing this problem. If you really really need to intercept HTTPS traffic, do the following:

- In fiddler go to Tools - Fiddler Options - HTTPS - Export root certificate to Desktop
- Locate the certificate you just exported (on desktop), install it as a trusted root CA.

After you've finished with fiddler **uninstall** the certificate, otherwise it's a serious security breach.

To uninstall certificate you need to run mmc.exe and select File - Add, there select sertificates. Then find `DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot` and remove it.

Note that basically it's a workaround. Do not forget to remove the certificate!

Comment: I tried what you say, I don't have any problem with web pages but my application does not allow me to authanticate when fiddler2 is running...

Comment: Do you use client authentication? What do you see in fiddler when trying to authenticate?

Comment: I will response in a few minutes, I will do screenshots.

Comment: You don't need to manually export the certificate to trust it; Fiddler will do this itself if you allow it. Failing to uninstall the root certificate is actually not a "serious security breach" in any way. The only way an attacker can make use of the certificate for malicious purposes is if they're already running their code on your computer, at which point you've already been compromised.

Comment: It actually is a security breach for the MITM attack. Being in a network of the user I'd be able to intercept traffic and impose say google.com using this certificate. Why do you think Fiddler warns you about trusting this cert? And auto-installation by fiddler did not work for me.

Comment: @Aneri: I think you might be confused. (In case you didn't know, I wrote Fiddler.) You can't use Fiddler's root certificate to attack another user "in a network" because the certificate is only trusted on the local machine. As to your "auto-installation" question, you should talk to me via the Help link in Fiddler, since millions of Fiddler users have used this successfully.

Comment: @EricLaw, I really might be confused, though I think that if somebody installs fiddler cert as a trusted CA, he will be endangered. I mean, I could create a new certificate for google.com using this cert, then redirect his traffic to my machine and give him the new cert. He will treat the cert as trusted since it is signed by manually added root CA. As about trusted installation in fiddler, maybe I was unlucky and something went wrong. I just posted a solution that worked for me.

Comment: @EricLaw or is this certificate unique for every machine you run fiddler on? If so, it will be much harder to use it for attack, though not completely impossible. But then I don't understand why call it 'DO_NOT_TRUST_...'.